# ¿Como puedo tabular conjuntos de texto en c++ para que al imprimirlos por pantalla se vean sin saltos de linea?

Tags: c++, matrices, salto-de-linea

¿Cómo puedo tabular estas matrices de forma que me queden sin saltos de línea entre ellas?
Solo estoy usando `#include<stdio.h>` y `#define TAM 100`

El código que tengo es este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 100
//Queremos calcular el producto de dos matrices cualesquiera dadas por el usuario//
int main()
{
int M1[TAM][TAM], M2[TAM][TAM], MR[TAM][TAM];
int fila_1, columna_1, fila_2, columna_2, i, j, k, l, h;
//Pedimos dimensiones de la primera matriz//
printf("Introduzca numero de filas de M1: ");
scanf("%d", &fila_1);
printf("Introduzca numero de columnas de M1: ");
scanf("%d", &columna_1);
//Pedimos dimensiones de la segunda matriz//
printf("Introduzca numero de filas de M2: ");
scanf("%d", &fila_2);
printf("Introduzca numero de columnas de M2: ");
scanf("%d", &columna_2);
//Comprobamos que las dimensiones de las matrices permiten operar//
if (columna_1 != fila_2)
{
    printf("No se puede realizar la operacion.");
}
else
{
    //Pedimos la primera matriz//
    for(i=0 ; i<fila_1 ; i++)
        for(j=0 ; j<columna_1 ; j++)
            {
                printf("\nDeme M1[%d][%d]: ",i+1,j+1);
                scanf("%d",&M1[i][j]);
            }
    //Pedimos la segunda matriz//
    for(k=0 ; k<fila_2 ; k++)
        for(l=0 ; l<columna_2 ; l++)
            {
                printf("\nDeme M2[%d][%d]",k+1,l+1);
                scanf("%d",&M2[k][l]);
            }
    //Mostramos las dos matrices para poder comprobar que estan bien//
    printf("\nLa primera matriz es:\n");
    for(i=0 ; i<fila_1 ; i++)
        {
        for(j=0 ; j<columna_1 ; j++)
            printf("%d\t",M1[i][j]);   
        printf("\n");                   
        }
    printf("\nLa segunda matriz es:\n");
    for(k=0 ; k<fila_2 ;  k++)
        {
        for(l=0 ; l<columna_2 ; l++)
            printf("%d\t",M2[k][l]);   
        printf("\n");                   
        }
    //Calculamos la matriz resultante y la mostramos por pantalla//
    for(i=0 ; i<fila_1 ; i++)
    {
        for(j=0 ; j<columna_1 ; j++)
        {
            for(l=0 ; l<columna_2 ; l++)
            {
                for(k=0, h=0 ; k<fila_2 ; k++)
                {
                    h = h + M1[i][j] * M2[k][l];
                    MR[i][l]=h;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nLa matriz resultado es:\n");
    for(i=0 ; i<fila_1 ; i++)
    {
        for(l=0 ; l<columna_2 ;l++)
            printf("%d\t", MR[i][l]);
        printf("\n");
    }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Prueba de escritorio:

Adjunto aquí como se ven en el cmd las matrices sin la tabulación a la que me refiero:
[image]

Comment: Recuerda que los caracteres \n hacen un salto de linea y si te fijas lo estas poniendo al inicio y al final, por eso se duplican, la solucion seria ponerlos solo al inicio o solo al final

Comment: Bienvenido. El código va como texto. Por favor muéstranos lo que obtienes y cómo lo quieres. (Mira como crear un [mre])

Comment: No veo que la pregunta use nada de C++. ¿Seguro que no es de C?

Answer (score 0):

El programa tiene varios errores a detallar:

1. Está incompleto.
2. No queda claro que es lo que se pretende hacer pues se carece de letra, la consiga se deduce del propio código.
3. Esta pregunta `if (C!=f)` no tiene respuesta directa antes del `else`, por lo que no queda claro que es lo que se pretende responder.
4. Para hacer lo que usted necesita, puede usar una variable contante llamada por ejemplo `colWidth` con valor de 10

El código quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM 3 // Definir TAM como 2 para una matriz de 2x2

int main() {
    int M1[TAM][TAM], M2[TAM][TAM], MR[TAM][TAM];
    const int colWidth = 10; // Definir el ancho de cada columna.
    
    // Entrada para los elementos de la primera matriz.
    printf("Ingrese los elementos de la primera matriz:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < TAM; j++) {
            printf("Deme M1[%d][%d]: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &M1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    // Entrada para los elementos de la segunda matriz.
    printf("\nIngrese los elementos de la segunda matriz:\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < TAM; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < TAM; l++) {
            printf("Deme M2[%d][%d]: ", k+1, l+1);
            scanf("%d", &M2[k][l]);
        }
    }
    
    // Mostrar la primera matriz
    printf("\nLa primera matriz es:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < TAM; j++) {
            printf("%-*d", colWidth, M1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    // Mostrar la segunda matriz
    printf("\nLa segunda matriz es:\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < TAM; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < TAM; l++) {
            printf("%-*d", colWidth, M2[k][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    // Multiplicación de matrices
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < TAM; l++) {
            MR[i][l] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < TAM; j++) {
                MR[i][l] += M1[i][j] * M2[j][l];
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Mostrar la matriz resultante
    printf("\nMatriz resultante despues de la multiplicacion:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < TAM; l++) {
            printf("%-*d", colWidth, MR[i][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buenas,  subí mi código completo y con aclaraciones de texto de lo q hace cada parte. Si pudieras explicarme exactamente que es lo que hace esa variable constante y el porque en el printf pones "%-*d" te lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: La variable constante colWidth se utiliza para definir el ancho de cada columna al imprimir las matrices en la consola. Especifica el número mínimo de caracteres que se imprimirán para cada elemento de la matriz. Si el número que se va a imprimir es más corto que este ancho, la salida se rellenará con espacios para garantizar que cada columna tenga un ancho consistente, lo que ayuda a alinear las columnas y hacer que la salida sea más legible.

Comment: El especificador de formato printf %-*d se utiliza para imprimir un número entero con un ancho específico. El * es un marcador de posición para un valor entero que especifica el ancho mínimo del campo de salida. El signo - indica justificación a la izquierda dentro del ancho de campo dado. El especificador d indica que el argumento es un número entero.

Comment: Entonces, cuando se utiliza printf("%-*d", colWidth, M1[i][j]); significa "imprimir el número entero M1[i][j] con un ancho mínimo de caracteres colWidth y justificar a la izquierda el número dentro de este espacio". Si colWidth es 10, por ejemplo, y M1[i][j] es el número 42, la salida será "42 " (con 8 espacios después del número para completar el ancho total de 10 caracteres).